# Limit for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^4}{x}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to solve this limit, but I'm not sure whether it's correct. The candidate limit is $l=0$.

From $ | \frac{x^2+y^4}{x} | $, since $\sqrt{x^2-y^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2} = |x| $, we then have:

$$| \frac{x^2+y^4}{x} | \leq | \frac{x^2+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}} | \leq ...$$

$$ ...\leq | \frac{r^2 cos^2 {\theta}+r^4 sin^4 {\theta}}{\sqrt{r^2 (cos^2 {\theta} - sin^2 {\theta})}} | \leq | \frac{r cos^2 {\theta}+r^3 sin^4 {\theta}}{\sqrt{(cos^2 {\theta} - sin^2 {\theta})}} \leq ... $$

$$ ... \leq | \frac{r+r^3}{\sqrt{cos(2\theta)}} | $$

The only case where the denominator is 0 is when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, this restriction is not a subset of the domain because we have $x \neq 0$ by hypothesis.
So the limit is 0.

Is this correct? I am not entirely sure about the last part!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$ and $\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}$ may be $0$, or even undefined, even when $x\ne0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval You mean, because $y^2$ could be greater than $x^2$, thus making the square root's argument negative? So the first inequality is incorrect? Same as $cos(2\theta)$: it could be negative. I see. Thanks. Do you have any idea on how to solve it?
Edit: looks like another user helped me with that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe, it's easier to reformulate $x+\frac{y^4}{x}$. Now insert $x_n=\frac{1}{n^4}$ and $y_n=\frac{c}{n}$.

Comment: This is not a correct argument, we can approch $(0,0)$ in such way $\theta \approx \frac \pi 2$, what matters is the speed.

Comment: @user So I've been doing this error for so long. What do you mean by speed? The value of the derivative near (0,0)? My first thought was about a curve like $x^{1/\alpha}$, where $\alpha$ is big, resambling the line $x=0$ near (0,0). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, we need explore this kind of paths.

Comment: $\frac{x^2+y^4}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$ does not exist for $y=\pm x$, so cannot be used to investigate initial fraction in whole $(0,0)$ neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest consider curve $y=\sqrt[8]{x}=x^{\frac{1}{8}}$. Then we have on this curve
$$\frac{x^2+y^4}{x}=x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
limit of first summand exists, while second tends to infinity.

On another hand (accordingly comments) along the curve $y=x$ limit is obviously zero. Thus, we can postulate, that limit does not exist.

Comment: Is this not true ? Am I right ? Because given limit approches to zero

Comment: @jacobianmatrix. How did you get that it is zero? Have you looked at my counterexample?

Comment: Let's take x=rcos(theta) and y=rsin(theta) and the limit is goes to zero.

Comment: @jacobianmatrix. One curve is not sufficient for the existence of a double limit. The double limit must exist over all possible curves. Thus, one counterexample suffices for negation.

Comment: Well done, but produce a second curve (with a finite limit), to prove that the global limit does not exist *at all*.

Comment: Thanks, @Anne Bauval. I hope $y=x$ is clear enough.

Comment: Indeed! Won't you append it to your answer?